# Rails 3 Migration update_all with relation / join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Given Following Models

```
class User
  has_many :conversations
end

class Conversation
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages
end

class Message
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

I want to remove the Conversation model and migrate the reference to a user to Message.
Normally I would use something like

```
add_column :messages, :user_id, :integer

Message.reset_column_information
Message.all.each do |message|
  message.user_id = message.conversation.user_id
end

remove_column :messages, :conversation_id
```

But in Production migrations run after the code was updated. Therefore this would throw an error.

Probably I just need a little hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution is to define a temporary model inside the migration -> [Source: Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Message should still have 'conversation_id' as a field even though you removed the belongs: to relationship right?

So what if you did:

message.user_id = User.find_by_id(message.conversation_id).user_id